# How to translate facebook location

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, user-registration

I´m using the FB:registration Plugin and it returns me as location an Array with something like *Munich, Cologne, etc*. I want them translated into german and save them as **München** or **Köln**.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the google translate API:

https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&q=Munich%20Cologne&source=en&target=de

Comment: Thanks for your help! This seems quite well. Is therefor a easy php solution too? may I run this with a if?